# Averaging XY data for locations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I wanted to find out mean of the selected points using QGIS. I tried out selecting using attribute table but could not find an option for mean in field calculator.

I have attached a screenshot with this.

[image: Mean XY data for selected rows]

Answer (score 3):

Pieside's answer gives you the straightforward way of doing it.  An alternative you may wish to consider is to use the 'Statistics by categories' tool in the `Processing` toolbox (just open the Processing toolbox and type `statistics` in the search bar and you'll find it.  This tool creates a table of basic statistics (min. mean, max, stdev, count) in one field based on categories in another field.  For example, if you have point data on street-corner fast food kiosks, you might have an attribute called 'Type' (e.g. hotdog, bagel, pizza, jellied_eels) and another attribute called 'Sales' (numerical field representing total income).  You can then quickly create a table giving basic statistics on how much money each type of fast food seller makes on average, the range of income and number of sellers.  The advantage of using this tool is it exports a table that you can save (perhaps to use in a report).

Answer (score 2):

In the menu, click on Vector->Analysis Tools->Basics statistics. See the end of: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html.

Comment: In the use-case in the OP's question, be sure to click the 'Use selected features only' option otherwise you will get stats on all points.